# What's the proper way to Add and Remove EventListener in C# Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, event-handling

Below are my two examples of how I register and unregister Unity Event Listener via C#.
However, I am not sure which one is "Correct", and the real difference in terms of use case.

If I accidentally Add Listener twice, what's the expected behaviour of my first case? Will it remove all the function with same function name?

Otherwise, will it be safer to use Case 2, register it as Action, and remove it when disabled?

Please advise me.

Just for example, I have an Example Function first.

```
private void ExampleFunction()
{
  Debug.Log("just example");
}
```

Case One: simply add and remove the registered function in single line

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    ExampleScript.ExampleEvent.AddListener(ExampleFunction);
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    ExampleScript.ExampleEvent.RemoveListener(ExampleFunction);
}
```

Case Two: registered "UnityAction" for the event, and remove the "UnityAction"

```
private UnityAction exampleAction = null;
private void OnEnable()
{
    ExampleScript.ExampleEvent.AddListener(exampleAction = () => { ExampleFunction(); });
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    ExampleScript.ExampleEvent.RemoveListener(exampleAction);
}
```

The above examples were used in some of my archived projects, but not sure which one is the best and secure method.

Comment: Actually, as for me, the most correct way to use UnityEvent - is not to use it at all :D

Comment: Both of the methods you have shown are valid and there isn't necessarily a "correct" method.

Comment: If I accidentally add "ExampleFunction" via AddListener 100 times(just saying) plus one "ExampleFunction" via inspector, will "ExampleFunction" remove all of them in my case one, including the inspector one?